# .NET Core / EF : how to avoid performance issue with Linq query?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a few questions on lambda filtering performance.

This is my code:

```
public class supplier 
{
    public Guid supplier_id { get; set; }
    public string supplier_name { get; set; }
    public Guid township_id { get; set; }
}

public class township
{
    public Guid township_id { get; set; }
    public string township { get; set; }
}
```

This is my dto class:

```
public class supplier_dto 
{
    public Guid supplier_id { get; set; }
    public string suppliername { get; set; }
    public Township township { get; set; }
}
```

So why I filter for list using Linq:

```
var supplier_list = (from sup on _dbcontext.suppliers
                     join twn on _dbcontext.townships on sup.township_id equals twn.township_id
                     select new supplier_dto  
                                {
                                    supplier_id = sup.supplier_id,
                                    suppliername = sup.supplier_name,
                                    township = getTownshipById(twn.township_id)
                                }).ToList();
```

If there are many suppliers, will this affect the performance? Is there a way to do without using `getTownshipById` function?

BR,
jm

Comment: did it not like `township = twn`.

from a different angle `_dbcontext.suppliers.include(x=>x.township`)` you could then where this...which will have the model on the parent so it wouldnt have to fetch after. You would have to put the TownShip on the suppier class

Comment: ps ideally supplier_dto would have the name and not the model. aka `string township` and not `Township township` where township is the name, aka renamed to TownShipName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your classes.
First, I assume you have one-to-many relationship between `township` and `suppliers`, which is typically represented by foreign key in the database. Therefore you have to have similar relationship in the model:

```
public class supplier 
{
    public Guid supplier_id { get; set; }
    public string supplier_name { get; set; }
    public Guid TownshipId { get; set; }
    public Township township { get; set; }
}

public class Township
{
    public Guid TownshipId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<supplier> suppliers { get; set; }
}
```

If that is the case, you can rewrite you LINQ statement:

```
var supplier_list = (from sup in _dbcontext.suppliers
                     select new supplier_dto  
                                {
                                    supplier_id = sup.supplier_id,
                                    suppliername = sup.supplier_name,
                                    township = sup.township
                                }).ToList();
```

Just make sure that `township` is actually loaded either through eager or explicit loading. In general, I consider it code smell if you need to use `join` in LINQ statement.

Second, the performance of LINQ query depends on the query that it generates. You put a label of .NET 3.1. In .NET 5 you can use an easy API `ToQueryString()` to get the resultant query; but even in 3.1 you can generate it with a little more effort.

Finally, your question doesn't have anything to do with `lambda`

Comment: Hi Felix, Thanks a lot. How about one to one relationship? that's meant 1 township to 1 supplier. How can I do it? beginner for net core project.

Comment: If it is one-to-one, then start with a single class. You will have hard time explaining why it is not good enough.